# Ignored default value in Lucee Orm

Tags: orm, cfml, lucee

I set my persistent component with this property:

```
<cfproperty name="active" ormType="timestamp" notnull="true" dbDefault="now()" />
```

Now, if I save an entity by not specifying its `created_at` value, I get an error: `not-null property references a null or transient value: User.active`.

How can I skip specifying all the columns when creating entities?

Thanks!

Comment: The error seems to relate to a property called `active` rather than `created_at`. Can you post a bit more code to clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks, you're right this is the code `<cfproperty name="active" ormtype="boolean" notnull="true" dbdefault="false" />`, when adding the entity I do `u = entityNew('user');
u.setEmail('mymail@domanin.com');
entitySave(u);`, the Db structure (Postgresql) seems ok, `ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN active boolean;
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN active SET NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN active SET DEFAULT false;`

Comment: OK, makes more sense. Have you tried using `default=false` rather than, or in addition to `dbdefault`. That should ensure the property does not have a null value when the entity is saved.

Comment: Also, for posterity, it would be best if you could edit your question so it shows the property you're asking about (ie `active` rather than `created_at`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than setting defaults in the database schema, I would define them in your entity's properties using the `default` attribute to avoid null values.

However, bear in mind that only simple and non-dynamic values - such as fixed strings and numbers - can be defined as defaults. If you need to define a complex value, like an array, or a dynamic one, such as `Now()`, you'll need to set those in the entity's `init()` method.

```
component name="user" accessors=true persistent=true{

 property name="active" ormtype="boolean" default=false;
 property name="created_at" ormtype="timestamp";

 function init(){
  variables.created_at=Now();
  return this;
 }

}
```